# SQL Create multiple tables at once

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to create multiple tables at once. Im having a hard time figuring out the correct method for accomplishing this. Currently my script looks like this:

```
  private function buildDB() {
    $sql = <<<MySQL_QUERY
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS headings (
type        VARCHAR(150),
heading     VARCHAR(100),
uniqueid    VARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS titles (
type        VARCHAR(150),
heading     VARCHAR(100),
uniqueid    VARCHAR(100)
)
MySQL_QUERY;

    return mysql_query($sql);
  }
```

Obviously, this doesn't work and no tables are created. Is there a simple way for creating multiple tables at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL is getting confused because you're not delimiting your queries. Add a semicolon after the first `CREATE` statement:

```
private function buildDB() {
    $sql = <<<MySQL_QUERY
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS headings (
        type        VARCHAR(150),
        heading     VARCHAR(100),
        uniqueid    VARCHAR(100)
        );

        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS titles (
        type        VARCHAR(150),
        heading     VARCHAR(100),
        uniqueid    VARCHAR(100)
        )
MySQL_QUERY;

    return mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Also, make sure `MySQL_QUERY` is at the beginning of the line with **no other characters, except maybe a semicolon**, as per the [Heredoc documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

---

Seeing as the above doesn't appear to work, give this code a try:

```
private function buildDB() {
    $sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS headings (
        type        VARCHAR(150),
        heading     VARCHAR(100),
        uniqueid    VARCHAR(100))";

    $sql2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS titles (
        type        VARCHAR(150),
        heading     VARCHAR(100),
        uniqueid    VARCHAR(100))";
MySQL_QUERY;

    return mysql_query($sql1) && mysql_query($sql2);
}
```

You *could* use `mysqli_multi_query()` (the MySQL version doesn't exist), but you'd have to use MySQLi then. The above code returns the logical AND of the two queries, so you still get a `0` returned if one fails.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working... do I need to swap out MYSQL_QUERY for MYSQL_MULTI_QUERY ?

Answer (score 2):

You can issue multiple queries as long as they are properly delimited.  When issuing multiple queries, change this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS headings (
type        VARCHAR(150),
heading     VARCHAR(100),
uniqueid    VARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS titles (
type        VARCHAR(150),
heading     VARCHAR(100),
uniqueid    VARCHAR(100)
)
```

to

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS headings (
type        VARCHAR(150),
heading     VARCHAR(100),
uniqueid    VARCHAR(100)
); // added a friendly semicolon

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS titles (
type        VARCHAR(150),
heading     VARCHAR(100),
uniqueid    VARCHAR(100)
); // added a friendly semicolon
```

and you should be set.

If not, throw some debugging in there to see exactly where your SQL or surrounding code is unhappy.

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thank you for helping fellow coders. Have your first upvote :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is because mysql_query() can execute only a single query at a time. Please try using mysqli::multi_query() instead (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) but do end your queries with a semi-colon.

The simplest approach however is to directly run the CREATE TABLE statements in your MySQL client

Comment: Where should I change them out? Just at the bottom where it says 'return mysql_query($sql)'?