# Create multiple tables at once

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Running multiple `CREATE TABLE` statements in redshift online query editor each ending with ';' is resulting only one table being created.

I looked at various posts on stack overflow where multiple tables were created on other platforms. Such as mysql here: [SQL Create multiple tables at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766865/sql-create-multiple-tables-at-once). However, I have not been able to find an example for redshift that works. I also tried to remove the last ';' which resulted in only the first table being created.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_one (
  test_col varchar(30),
  test_two varchar(30)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_two (
  test_col varchar(30),
  test_two varchar(30)
);
```

There are no error codes, but only test_two is created.

Answer (score 1):

This certainly works on Redshift. If you're using Python and Psycopg2 to execute these queries, ensure there is a semi-colon `;` after each query, and that there are no wild semi-colons, because you'll get as it'll be an empty query.

Also, see to it that you `commit` the connection after you're executing the queries. If you're using an SQL Client like DBeaver/PgAdmin, turn on auto-commit or manually commit after executing these queries.

**Edit**

When you're using the Redshift console query editor, it only executes one query (the last query) at a time, whether those are DDL or DML queries. 
So as of now it's not possible to CREATE multiple tables or INSERT data to multiple tables. You can use a an SQL Client to achieve this.

Comment: Commit is not needed for DDL, correct? So that can't be an issue.

Comment: I am just entering them in the redshift counsel query editor, I will update original question with that detail.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer after you've mentioned that you're using the Redshift Console query. Please mark the answer as accepted if it resolves your query.

Answer (score 1):

Redshift online query editor does not support multiple queries. You have to select individual query to execute. Better use `psql` or [tools](https://dwgeek.com/best-amazon-redshift-query-tools-sql-editors.html/) like Aginity for Redshift to execute multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned what tool you are using, hence assuming `psql` command prompt.

In `my.sql`, I have just `copied` and `pasted` the question `sql`.
If you run following query, it will create two example table fine without any issues.

```
psql -h example-url.redshift.amazonaws.com -U user -d example_db -p 5439 -f /home/your/path/to/sql/file/my.sql
```

Output

```
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
```

Hope it helps, please update question if you need more information.

Comment: What should we do if it's asking password for every time? Is there any parameter to use the password in the same line?